# Swift 3 Core Data Migration with Progress Indicator or Activity Spinner

Tags: ios, swift, data-migration

I've made some changes to the data model in one of my apps that can be handled automatically via lightweight migration. People who have used the app for a while will have lots of data, so when they install the new version, the data migration will take quite a while (as much as 5-10 minutes).  I'd like to find a way to display a message and an activity spinner, or progress indicator while the migration is taking place so that they don't think the app has frozen. There is a tutorial in Tim Roadley's core data book that requires a manual migration.  Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the book to which you're referring, but it is possible to perform a lightweight migration behind a progress indicator. From the [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html):

> If you want to determine in advance whether Core Data can infer the mapping between the source and destination models without actually doing the work of migration, you can use `NSMappingModel`’s `inferredMappingModelForSourceModel:destinationModel:error`: method. This returns the inferred model if Core Data is able to create it, otherwise nil.

So, you'll need to:

1. Detect if migration is required.
2. Display progress indicator and start migrating.
3. When migration is finished, load your main UI.